# Auto populate user id based on login info

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on a sales CRM database in MS access 2010. I am trying to auto populate usernames in various forms.

The DB loads to a login page, asking for username and password. The username is set in the Employee table, not based on Windows login. The employee table has the following fields (EmpID PK, firstname, lastname, phone, email, notes, title, username TEXT, password).

I have two tables (Customer Contact and Leads) that require an employee to 'take ownership' of the activity. I would like the employee field to auto populate based on who is logged in.

Here is the code behind the OK button on my login page:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
If IsNull(Me.txtUserID) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter user name.", vbInformation, "User Name Required"
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter password.", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
    'process the job
    If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserName]", "tblEmployee", "[UserName] ='" & Me.txtUserID.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect user name or password."
    Else
        Me.Visible = False
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmHome"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Environ("username") will return the value of the current users username. Using environ("userdomain") will return the value of the current users domain.

In your immediate window, do a ?Environ("username") to test and see what you get

On the form where you want users to take ownership, you can have a command button the user clicks to take ownership, you can get the users username from Environ("username") and update the user as the owner in your table.

No need for the logon page (unless you want extra security), your application will always know who the user is.

Also, in your queries that feed your forms, you can have =Environ("username") as the from argument on the username field to show the users the records they own.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to either store the users name in a global variable, or write it to a temporary table.

To store it in a global variable simply declare it in a module

```
Dim strUser as String
```

Then modify your login form code like this

```
If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserName]", "tblEmployee", "[UserName] ='" & Me.txtUserID.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect user name or password."
Else
    Me.Visible = False
    strUser=Me.txtUserID.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmHome"
End If
```

This has the downside of having its value dropped any time a debug/error occurs that is unhandled. It has the upside of being fast and easy to use.

EDIT:
I would go for a local table personally. Make sure you `DELETE * FROM tblLocalTableName` on application close/logout, and on startup. If you need help with either implementation, let me know.

EDIT: 
For a local table, create a table in Access in the frontend file. Lets call it 'tblLocalVars'. Primary key text field, lets name it 'Key', and another text field, let's call it 'Val'. Add a row to this table, Key='LoggedUser' and leave Val empty.

Then on your login form, the code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
If IsNull(Me.txtUserID) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter user name.", vbInformation, "User Name Required"
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter password.", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
    'process the job
    If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserName]", "tblEmployee", "[UserName] ='" & Me.txtUserID.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect user name or password."
    Else
        CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE tblLocalVars SET Val='" & Me.txtUserID & "' WHERE Key='LoggedUser'"
        Me.Visible = False
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmHome"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Now whenever you want to get the current users username, you can use this:

```
Dlookup("Val","tblLocalVars", "Key='LoggedUser'")
```

Now you just need to add this to the logout code:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE tblLocalVars SET Val='' WHERE Key='LoggedUser'"
```

Make sure you add this code to the Unload event on your login form.

Comment: JCro, thanks for the reply.  Is there any chance you could give me further details on how to implement the local table?

Comment: @zekeinvestor Updated answer